# Can't import the name export 'memo' from non EcmaScript module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Failed to compile
> ./node_modules/@monaco-editor/react/dist/index.mjs
> Can't import the named export 'memo' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

I tried to solve this by both methods of exports, but still shows this error, what should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*both methods of exports*".

Comment: Most likely referring to named and default exports. Nevertheless we need you to see code in order to assist you.